# dumping several objects into the same file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pickle

Let's say I have a dictionary of about 100k pairs of strings, and a numpy matrix of shape (100k, 500). I would like to save them to the disk in a same file.

What I'm doing right now is using cPickle to dump the dictionary, and scipy.io.savemat to dump the matrix. This way, the dump / load is very fast. But the problem is that since I use different methods I obtain 2 files, and I would like to have just one file containing my 2 objects. How can I do this?

I could cPickle them both in the same file, but cPickle is incredibly slow on big arrays.

Comment: Have you tried using a higher pickle protocol? Protocol 0, which is the default for Python2.7, converts everything to ASCII, whereas protocols 1 and 2 produce a binary output (be sure to open the output files in binary mode, i.e. `'wb'` rather than `'w'`). [`joblib.dump`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html) is another very fast method for serializing heterogeneous collections of arrays and Python objects.

Comment: Look at `np.savez`.  It saves each variable to a file in a zip archive (which may be compressed).  You could pack a bunch of small not numpy objects in a dictionary or list which will be saved with pickle.  `load` is lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dill`.  `dill.dump` accesses and uses the `dump` method from `numpy` to store an `array` or `matrix` object, so it's stored the same way it would be if you did it directly from the method on the `numpy` object.  You'd just `dill.dump` the dictionary.

`dill` also has the ability to store pickles in compressed format, but it's slower.  As mentioned in the comments, there's also `joblib`, which can also do the same as `dill`…  but basically, `joblib` leverages `cloudpickle` (which is another serializer) or can also use `dill`, to do the serialization.

If you have a huge dictionary, and don't need all of the contents at once… maybe a better option would be `klepto`, which can use advanced serialization methods (from `dill`) to store a `dict` to several files on disk (or a database), where you have a proxy `dict` in memory that enables you to only get the entries you need.

All of these packages give you a fast unified `dump` for standard python and also for `numpy` objects.